# error with dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a typed dataset userProfile which is same as a user table in my data base.
I am using a stored procedure which changes a password and return a single row of the same user.But when i am using this procedure in .cs code an sql exception telling

```
[There is no row at position 0.]

in public UserRow this[int index] {
Line 413:                get {
Line 414:                    return ((UserRow)(this.Rows[index]));
Line 415:                }
Line 416:            }
```

but my password in being changed..

this is my stored procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_Campaign_PasswordChange]
@username varchar(50),
@old_password varchar(50),
@new_password varchar(50)

as

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
if exists(select "USER_ID" from "User" where User_Login_Id=@username and Password=@old_password)
   begin

   select User_Id  from "User" where User_Login_Id=@username
   update "User" set Password=@new_password where User_Login_Id=@username


   end 

   else
   RAISERROR ('username or password does not exists',10,1)


 COMMIT TRANSACTION      




END TRY     

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RETURN @@ERROR
END CATCH
```

but if i write the select statement at the end then no error is generated

plz help

Comment: One tip, prefer using `usp` for prefixing your stored procs, rather then `sp`.

Comment: @Jason - Good point it is actually the `sp_` that causes the problem. SQL Server will look for these in the master database first.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public UserRow this[int index] {
          get {
                  if(this.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                   return ((UserRow)(this.Rows[index]));
                }
 return null;
           }
  }

var row = this[0];

if (row != null){ // Do something }
```

Comment: this part code is system generated i created the dataset using table adapter and this is code generated automatically.should i make this change?